# JIT-ed Exception handler implementation

Tags: .net, assembly, exception, clr, il

Consider the following IL code:

```
    .method public static void Main()
    {
        ldstr "Starts Here"
        call void [mscorlib] System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        .try {      
            ldstr "Try Me!"
            call void [mscorlib] System.Console::WriteLine(string)
            leave.s Done
        }
        catch [mscorlib] System.Exception {
            ldstr "Catch Me!"
            call void [mscorlib] System.Console::WriteLine(string)
            leave.s Done
        }
    Done:
        ldstr "Ends Here"
        call void [mscorlib] System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        ret
    }
```

How does CLR define the `try` block in JIT-ed code? The native code looks the following way:

```
...
00900076 8b0538214703    mov     eax,dword ptr ds:[3472138h] ("Starts Here")
...

00900090 8b053c214703    mov     eax,dword ptr ds:[347213Ch] ("Try Me!")
...

009000a2 eb1b            jmp     009000bf ;// Done

009000a4 8945d4          mov     dword ptr [ebp-2Ch],eax
009000a7 8b0540214703    mov     eax,dword ptr ds:[3472140h] ("Catch Me!")
...

009000b8 e888293b73      call    clr!JIT_EndCatch (73cb2a45)
009000bd eb00            jmp     009000bf ;// Done

;// Done:
009000bf 8b0544214703    mov     eax,dword ptr ds:[3472144h] ("Ends Here")
...
009000d6 c3              ret
```

We can see `clr!JIT_EndCatch` but where is the beginning and the end of the `try` block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jitter generates a lot more than just the machine code that you can easily see with the debugger.  You'll want to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17131389/17034), it talks about the tables that the jitter generates to assist the garbage collector.

That works in a very similar way for exception handling, the jitter generates function tables used by the SafeSEH implementation to let the operating system discover the exception filter.  Such a table has entries for the start and end address of the try-block and a function pointer for the filter.  The exact way it works is heavily under-documented, exception handling has been exploited heavily by malware in the past and google hits for "safeseh" are not anything I want to repeat here.  There's some cursory info about it in the MSDN article for the [assembler's option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a89h429.aspx).  I'm not aware of a simple way to inspect these tables with the debugger.